# RTPbin receiving two sources with same codec randomly swaps sinks

Tags: gstreamer, gstreamer-1.0

I am receiving two UDP streams synchronized via NTP clock using RTPBin, to be ingested by my own application using two appsinks, as seen in the below pipeline. This works fine 90% of the time when the application is run.

```
rtpbin name=rtpbin latency=80 \
udpsrc caps=\"application/x-rtp,media=(string)video,clock-rate=(int)90000,encoding-name=(string)H264\" \
port=40322 ! rtpbin.recv_rtp_sink_0 \
rtpbin. ! rtph264depay ! queue ! avdec_h264 ! videoconvert ! video/x-raw,format=RGBA,width=1296,height=972 ! appsink name=appsink_0_left \
udpsrc port=40323 ! rtpbin.recv_rtcp_sink_0 \
udpsrc caps=\"application/x-rtp,media=(string)video,clock-rate=(int)90000,encoding-name=(string)H264\" \
port=40320 ! rtpbin.recv_rtp_sink_1 \
rtpbin. ! rtph264depay ! avdec_h264 ! videoconvert ! video/x-raw,format=RGBA,width=1296,height=972 ! appsink name=appsink_1_right \
udpsrc port=40321 ! rtpbin.recv_rtcp_sink_1
```

However, upon execution, sometimes the two rtpbin sessions will be swapped and appsink #0 will receive stream #1 instead of stream #0, and vice-versa. This occurs at a seemingly random frequency. My application involves stereo mapping, therefore it is important that each appsink receives the right numbered stream.

In theory each RTP session is numbered by the RTPBIN, and is then sent as recv_rtp_src_%u_%u_%u (where the first %u is the session number) to the rtph264depay. Unfortunately rec_rtp_src_%u_%u_%u is generated dynamically and does not seem to be accessible, and you have to use RTPBin. which automatically selects the first available stream with the lowest number, which is the correct one 90% of the time but occasionally the wrong one.

Is there a way to select which RTP session/stream gets delivered to which sink? Alternatively, is there another way to receive two UDP streams, synchronize them and have them outputted to the correct sinks?

Answer (score 0):

This just can't be done with a gstreamer pipeline. All you can do is create the sessions dynamically and then assign the correct appsink to each.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the SSRC in the RTP header to ensure to differentiate the pipeline.
If remember correctly SSRC value is one of the names in (recv_rtp_src_%u_%u_%u).

If you cannot enforce the SSRC in the video source, you could try to run this pipeline as two separate pipelines.